# Removing warning icons from Java file and packages in Eclipse project explorer

Tags: java, eclipse

I used to use IntelliJ, the warning icons in the eclipse project explorers are kind of distracting me what I am doing. Is there any way to disable these warnings from package and class names? But the validation should not be disabled, **just only from project explorer**. 
This is, the warnings should be only in the editor. I think this also increases the performance of Eclipse by avoiding extra calculations.

This is how Intellij IDEA works with warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Window > Preferences > Validation` and disable validation for whatever types of files you want.

Edit: Hmm. There's also `Window > Appearance > Label Decorations`, but that didn't seem to disable the decorations in the explorer view.

Comment: updated my question I don't want to disable the validation, thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing available to hide the problem markers in the explorer view (and no, that doesn't cost any performance overhead as markers are persistent and can directly be queried for each resource).

One (bad) workaround would be to use the Navigator view instead, but that one really only shows the file and folder structure, so the package layout and similar Java specific things are gone then.

Also, in a typical Eclipse setup, your icons will not only be overlayed by the warnings indicator, but also by SCM overlay, project type overlay, disabled optional compiler warnings overlay and a multitude of other overlays. You should get used to this.

Answer (score 0):

go to Windows-show view-other-Problem.

now open the Problems tab which is in the lower screen, in this tab you can see all errors and warnings your project had.

If the problem in the build path, open the build path and remove the JREs which have warning or error and delete them, then import them one more time by import external JREs.

Remember that before you run the project to make a clean from project tab.

OR you can from the problems tab to right click at the warning and choose Quick fix, sometimes this work.

If that not sussced please inform me to found the another solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `@SuppressWarnings` **annotations** to be more selective about which warnings you want to suppress.

Comment: I just dont want to see the warning icons in project explorer, the warning validation should be available only editing the class. Thanks!

Comment: You won't see the warning in project explorer and it is easy to search a file for a suppressed warning.

Comment: Sorry, but using warnings suppression (i.e. _disabling_ it for a certain piece of code) just for _visually_ removing it is certainly not the way a responsible developer should take.

Comment: @Bananeweizen Neither is disabling validation entirely. How come Bru2Rat7 doesn't get a -1? I was just pointing out a possible solution that is more flexible.